# From Extjs to Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4.2

I was built an app with Extjs 4.2 and I need to adapt it to mobile using Sencha Touch , So I need to transform my existing code in Extjs to Sencha Touch , is there any tool to make it automatically or I should begin all from scratch ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new app with Touch framework. All business logic code will be same in Ext JS and Touch app. So you can use Ext JS code, need to change some config property based on touch framework.

Comment: so I will change only view code if i have mvc architecter ?

Comment: yes Mainly you have to focus on View code because this is part of UI.